# Visual Studio 2010 Live555

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, live555

I have problem developing with live555. I already build the lib-files and example projects with the make files.
But if I try to develop something on my own it doesn't work out. After including the headers liveMedia.hh, BasicUsageEnvironment.hh GroupsockHelper.hh (I set the include path to all .hh-files and libary-ath to all lib-files) I get this errors:

```
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(91): warning C4005: 'AF_IPX': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(460): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'AF_IPX'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(131): warning C4005: 'AF_MAX': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(479): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'AF_MAX'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(168): warning C4005: 'SO_DONTLINGER': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(402): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'SO_DONTLINGER'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(212): error C2011: 'sockaddr': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(485): Siehe Deklaration von 'sockaddr'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(390): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: 'Konstante'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(390): error C3805: 'Konstante': unerwartetes Token, es wurde entweder '}' oder ein ',' erwartet
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(524): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSA': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(287): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IN_CLASSA'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(530): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSB': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(293): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IN_CLASSB'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(536): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSC': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(299): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IN_CLASSC'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(547): warning C4005: 'INADDR_ANY': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(304): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'INADDR_ANY'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(549): warning C4005: 'INADDR_BROADCAST': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(306): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'INADDR_BROADCAST'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2def.h(583): error C2011: 'sockaddr_in': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(312): Siehe Deklaration von 'sockaddr_in'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(132): error C2011: 'fd_set': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(68): Siehe Deklaration von 'fd_set'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(167): warning C4005: 'FD_SET': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(102): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'FD_SET'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(176): error C2011: 'timeval': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(111): Siehe Deklaration von 'timeval'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(232): error C2011: 'hostent': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(167): Siehe Deklaration von 'hostent'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(245): error C2011: 'netent': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(180): Siehe Deklaration von 'netent'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(252): error C2011: 'servent': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(187): Siehe Deklaration von 'servent'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(264): error C2011: 'protoent': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(199): Siehe Deklaration von 'protoent'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(360): error C2011: 'WSAData': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(322): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAData'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(458): error C2011: 'sockproto': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(494): Siehe Deklaration von 'sockproto'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(500): error C2011: 'linger': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(531): Siehe Deklaration von 'linger'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(513): warning C4005: 'SOMAXCONN': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(544): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'SOMAXCONN'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(542): warning C4005: 'FD_READ': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(562): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'FD_READ'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(545): warning C4005: 'FD_WRITE': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(563): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'FD_WRITE'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(548): warning C4005: 'FD_OOB': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(564): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'FD_OOB'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(551): warning C4005: 'FD_ACCEPT': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(565): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'FD_ACCEPT'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(554): warning C4005: 'FD_CONNECT': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(566): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'FD_CONNECT'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(557): warning C4005: 'FD_CLOSE': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(567): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'FD_CLOSE'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1578): error C2375: 'accept': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(742): Siehe Deklaration von 'accept'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1600): error C2375: 'bind': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(747): Siehe Deklaration von 'bind'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1619): error C2375: 'closesocket': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(752): Siehe Deklaration von 'closesocket'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1638): error C2375: 'connect': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(754): Siehe Deklaration von 'connect'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1659): error C2375: 'ioctlsocket': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(759): Siehe Deklaration von 'ioctlsocket'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1680): error C2375: 'getpeername': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(764): Siehe Deklaration von 'getpeername'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1701): error C2375: 'getsockname': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(769): Siehe Deklaration von 'getsockname'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1724): error C2375: 'getsockopt': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(774): Siehe Deklaration von 'getsockopt'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1745): error C2375: 'htonl': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(781): Siehe Deklaration von 'htonl'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1762): error C2375: 'htons': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(783): Siehe Deklaration von 'htons'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1780): error C2375: 'inet_addr': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(785): Siehe Deklaration von 'inet_addr'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1797): error C2375: 'inet_ntoa': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(787): Siehe Deklaration von 'inet_ntoa'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1815): error C2375: 'listen': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(789): Siehe Deklaration von 'listen'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1833): error C2375: 'ntohl': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(793): Siehe Deklaration von 'ntohl'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1850): error C2375: 'ntohs': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(795): Siehe Deklaration von 'ntohs'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1870): error C2375: 'recv': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(797): Siehe Deklaration von 'recv'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1895): error C2375: 'recvfrom': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(803): Siehe Deklaration von 'recvfrom'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1921): error C2375: 'select': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(811): Siehe Deklaration von 'select'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1945): error C2375: 'send': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(818): Siehe Deklaration von 'send'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1970): error C2375: 'sendto': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(824): Siehe Deklaration von 'sendto'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(1996): error C2375: 'setsockopt': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(832): Siehe Deklaration von 'setsockopt'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2018): error C2375: 'shutdown': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(839): Siehe Deklaration von 'shutdown'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2039): error C2375: 'socket': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(843): Siehe Deklaration von 'socket'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2063): error C2375: 'gethostbyaddr': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(850): Siehe Deklaration von 'gethostbyaddr'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2083): error C2375: 'gethostbyname': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(855): Siehe Deklaration von 'gethostbyname'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2101): error C2375: 'gethostname': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(857): Siehe Deklaration von 'gethostname'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2121): error C2375: 'getservbyport': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(861): Siehe Deklaration von 'getservbyport'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2141): error C2375: 'getservbyname': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(865): Siehe Deklaration von 'getservbyname'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2160): error C2375: 'getprotobynumber': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(869): Siehe Deklaration von 'getprotobynumber'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2178): error C2375: 'getprotobyname': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(871): Siehe Deklaration von 'getprotobyname'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2200): error C2375: 'WSAStartup': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(875): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAStartup'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2219): error C2375: 'WSACleanup': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(879): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSACleanup'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2236): error C2375: 'WSASetLastError': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(881): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSASetLastError'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2253): error C2375: 'WSAGetLastError': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(883): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAGetLastError'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2270): error C2375: 'WSAIsBlocking': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(885): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAIsBlocking'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2287): error C2375: 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(887): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2304): error C2375: 'WSASetBlockingHook': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(889): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSASetBlockingHook'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2321): error C2375: 'WSACancelBlockingCall': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(891): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSACancelBlockingCall'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2343): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByName': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(893): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAAsyncGetServByName'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2370): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(901): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2396): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(909): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2421): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(916): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2446): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(923): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2473): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(930): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2496): error C2375: 'WSACancelAsyncRequest': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(939): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSACancelAsyncRequest'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock2.h(2517): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncSelect': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(941): Siehe Deklaration von 'WSAAsyncSelect'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(75): error C2079: 'sockaddr_gen::Address' verwendet undefiniertes struct 'sockaddr'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(76): error C2079: 'sockaddr_gen::AddressIn' verwendet undefiniertes struct 'sockaddr_in'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(119): warning C4005: 'IP_TOS': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(352): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IP_TOS'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(120): warning C4005: 'IP_TTL': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(351): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IP_TTL'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(121): warning C4005: 'IP_MULTICAST_IF': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(346): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IP_MULTICAST_IF'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(122): warning C4005: 'IP_MULTICAST_TTL': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(347): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IP_MULTICAST_TTL'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(123): warning C4005: 'IP_MULTICAST_LOOP': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(348): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IP_MULTICAST_LOOP'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(124): warning C4005: 'IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(349): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(125): warning C4005: 'IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(350): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(126): warning C4005: 'IP_DONTFRAGMENT': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(353): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'IP_DONTFRAGMENT'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(193): error C2079: '_SOCKADDR_INET::Ipv4' verwendet undefiniertes struct 'sockaddr_in'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2ipdef.h(700): error C2011: 'ip_mreq': 'struct' Typneudefinition
1>          C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsock.h(363): Siehe Deklaration von 'ip_mreq'
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h(664): error C3861: "WSASetLastError": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h(671): error C3861: "WSASetLastError": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h(709): error C3861: "WSASetLastError": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h(716): error C3861: "WSASetLastError": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h(760): error C3861: "WSASetLastError": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h(767): error C3861: "WSASetLastError": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h(807): error C3861: "WSASetLastError": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
1>C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h(814): error C3861: "WSASetLastError": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
1>c:\live\groupsock\include\NetCommon.h(35): warning C4005: 'EWOULDBLOCK': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          c:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\errno.h(132): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'EWOULDBLOCK'
1>c:\live\groupsock\include\NetCommon.h(36): warning C4005: 'EINPROGRESS': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          c:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\errno.h(104): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'EINPROGRESS'
1>c:\live\groupsock\include\NetCommon.h(37): warning C4005: 'EAGAIN': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          c:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\errno.h(50): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'EAGAIN'
1>c:\live\groupsock\include\NetCommon.h(38): warning C4005: 'EINTR': Makro-Neudefinition
1>          c:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\errno.h(43): Siehe vorherige Definition von 'EINTR'
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have conflict with "windows.h" and "winsock2.h" inclusion

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
```

More informations here

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737629(VS.85).aspx?ppud=4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737629%28VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4)

[C++ Redefinition Header Files (winsock2.h)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372480/c-redefinition-header-files)