# Winsock redefinition errors

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winsock, redefinition

I am compiling a project in Visual C++ 2010, but I have problems with some Winsock redefinitions.

First of all I get:

```
syntax error : identifier 'SOCKADDR_STORAGE'
```

But if I include winsock or winsock2 or ws2tcpip i get many errors like these:

```
error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition 
error C2011: 'WSAData' : 'struct' type redefinition
error C2011: 'linger' : 'struct' type redefinition
```

Comment: Could you post a code sample? Also try adding `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`

Comment: Let's see the `#include` block from the offending module.

Comment: I dont have any fancy includes, i have these //#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
//#include <wininet.h> i have to include them in few .cpp files.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372480/c-redefinition-header-files-winsock2-h

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem is that by including `Windows.h`, you are also already including `winsock.h`. It is here your problem arises as including `winsock2.h` or `ws2tcpip.h` will attempt to redefine some of the definitions in `winsock.h`

By using `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before your `Windows.h` include you stop the compiler from including a lot of the extra stuff that comes with `Windows.h`

Comment: After spending a ton of time trying to solve this issue, your explanation is the one that not only worked but also made complete sense. Thanks!