# Cannot include both files (WinSock2, Windows.h)

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock2

I'm having a problem including both files.
Now, I know I need to either include Winsock2 first, then windows.h, or simply put:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

but, I'm still having problems

I have a header file that is called `XS.h` which looks like this

```
#ifndef XS_H
#define XS_H

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#endif
```

and I'm including `XS.h` in the header `Client.h`.
`Client.h` include is looks like this :

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include "XS.h"
```

`XS.h` is my only include in `Client.h`, yet I still get errors (and as you can see, `Winsock`is included before `windows.h`

I'm getting about 78 errors, here are some of them :

```
Error   90  error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\ws2tcpip.h   703
Error   61  error C2375: 'WSAStartup' : redefinition; different linkage c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winsock2.h   2296
Error   49  error C2375: 'send' : redefinition; different linkage   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winsock2.h   2026
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Edit: I've tried to use `#define _WINSOCKAPI_` as well, though it did not resolve my problems...
I have `winsock.h` first, then `windows.h`, though it still does the error for me.

Comment: use `#pragma once` in header file

Comment: I suggest to always include windows.h and windowsx.h first, in every source file (preferably using the stdafx.h file). I'm not sure it solves this particular problem, but it reduces confusion a lot.

Comment: I've changed `Client.h` includes to this :
`#pragma once

#include <winsock2.h>


#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include "Chat.h"`

though it still doesnt work, same errors....

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372480/c-redefinition-header-files

Comment: MIcrosoft's "Intellisense" doesn't use the same analysis engine as the compiler proper, and so it can and does spit out "error messages" for perfectly valid code. That said, this sounds as a real problem, not just an Intellisense apparent-problem. You should always include `windows.h` before including any other Windows API header. That's because Microsoft headers generally do not include all that they need, i.e. do not follow good programming practice. It's possible to just make `<windows.>` a forced include, but that repeats the malpractice that caused the problem: better fix the source.

Comment: I've edit my post for an easier understanding.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure that `<windows.h>` doesn't include `<winsock.h>` (which provides many of the same declarations as `<winsock2.h>`). In the `<winsock2.h>` file on my system there is this line:

```
#define _WINSOCKAPI_   /* Prevent inclusion of winsock.h in windows.h */
```

The **`_WINSOCKAPI_`** include guard may be an internal implementation detail, but as a practical solution I would rely on it, just defining this symbol before including `<windows.h>`, e.g. in the compiler invocation (which for an IDE means in the IDE project settings).

Alternatively you can try to [always include `<winsock2.h>` before `<windows.h>`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/winsock2.h%20include%20order), in order to establish the relevant include guard whatever it is (but this is I think much more fragile than just assuming that the above guard is practically well-defined);

or you can define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, which prevents `<windows.h>` from including `<winsock.h>` but also some other headers (listing from source on my system those are `<cderr.h>`, `<dde.h>`, `<ddeml.h>`, `<dlgs.h>`, `<lzexpand.h>`, `<mmsystem.h>`, `<nb30.h>`, `<rpc.h>`, `<shellapi.h>`, `<winperf.h>`, `<wincrypt.h>`, `<winefs.h>`, `<winscard.h>`, `<winspool.h>`, `<ole2.h>`, and `<commdlg.h>`). I do not recommend relying on `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` optimization for *correctness*.

I.e., minimum:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef _WINSOCKAPI_
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

auto main()
    -> int
{}
```

Comment: turns out, I was including windows.h in my main source file, which caused the problems, and then the `WINSOCKAPI` fixed the other erros...
Thanks!

Comment: Is the `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`not the best choice? Why isn't it working? What is the inclusion order when using it?

Comment: Apparently there's no clearly "best" choice. Consider for example using third party headers that depend on `<windows.h>` dragging in one or more of those headers excluded by `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`. The [original documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20121219084749/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166474) just defines the effect as "refer to Windows.H to determine the files that will be excluded". So both approaches are based on looking up the MS header code, which is subject to change. Maybe use both when there's no problem with having the listed headers excluded.

Answer (score 5):

I made sure that an `#include "Winsock2.h"` is before any `#include "windows.h"` and `"#include "Winsock.h"` and this solved the case.

Just a matter of patience, look at includes one by one and establish this order, first  `#include "Winsock2.h"` then `#include "windows.h"`

I checked the recursive includes, I spotted the header files which include (recursively) some #include "windows.h" and "#include "Winsock.h"and write a#include "Winsock2.h". in this files, i added#include "Winsock2.h"` as the first include.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but the above solution does not work always.  There are 3rd party libraries that can and will include windows.h unbeknownst to you.  A good example that has bit me: Qt's header file QSGGeometry. 
My preference is to define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN for any (CMake) modules that don't need winsock.

Answer (score 1):

Add the includes to pch.h:

```
// TODO: add headers that you want to pre-compile here
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")
```

Answer (score 0):

the key is set pre-complie define
WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

you need to set it, and recheck include.

because not set it, MFC framework will throw a message "#error WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <Windows.h>"