# Why does MinGW-w64 require winsock2 to be manually included?

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2, mingw-w64

Some code and associated warnings/errors:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
int main() { }
```

> F:/Prog/mingw-w64/x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v3-rev1/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/ws2ipdef.h:71:3: error: '`ADDRESS_FAMILY`' does not name a type
>
> ```
> ADDRESS_FAMILY si_family;
> ```

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
int main() { }     // this compiles successfully, only gives warning
```

> F:/Prog/mingw-w64/x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v3-rev1/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:15:2: warning: #warning Please include winsock2.h before windows.h [-Wcpp]

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
int main() { }
```

> (compilation successful).

My questions are:

- Why doesn't `iphlpapi.h` (and other files that rely on winsock) do `#include <winsock2.h>` themself, or at least give a nicer error message?
- Why does there a warning for it  to come before `windows.h` ?

Comment: About the warning part, the original file from MS has problems with the include order too. Windows.h defines some things of winsock2..h too if they aren´t defined yet, but different. Winsock2.h has to be the first to get the right definitions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399650/cannot-include-both-files-winsock2-windows-h addresses this issue too

Comment: @deviantfan that answer seemed to explain that this order was required, but not why

Comment: For what it's worth, your second example doesn't compile in Visual Studio either, and the mountain of errors is much less friendly. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja it does compile successfully, just gives a `#warning` on the way

Answer (score 16):

`windows.h` includes `winsock.h` by default.  `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h` *do not* coexist.  If `winsock2.h` is included first, it disables `winsock.h`, and all is good.  But if `winsock.h` is included first, `winsock2.h` fails to compile, because it redeclares a lot of things that `winsock.h` already declares.  Thus why you need to include `winsock2.h` first.

Microsoft wants people to use one or the other, not both.  `winsock2.h` is meant to *replace* `winsock.h` rather than *supplement* it.  But why they made `winsock2.h` so incompatible that it completely breaks if `winsock.h` is included first is anyone's guess.  They could have just as easily made `winsock2.h` `#ifdef` any duplicate declarations to avoid errors.  Or even have `winsock2.h` include `winsock.h` for the declarations.  But they didn't.

Comment: mingw-w64 does actually work if you include winsock2 second (it only gives a #warning) . Maybe mingw-w64 doesn't support winsock1 at all, or maybe it went ahead and did those "just as easily" things.

Comment: I suspect mingw's version of `windows.h` is including `winsock2.h` instead of `winsock.h`, if it is including either one of them at all.

Comment: I don't think it's including either, as my first program would have compiled if so