# type errors in Mingw-x64

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build my project (wpilib) on windows, coming from linux where it works fine. I installed mingw, but that didn't seem to have all the threading stuff I'm using, so I deleted it and installed mingw-x64. That got me further, but now I'm stuck here.

```
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:55:0,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/detail/socket_types.hpp:38,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/detail/win_tss_ptr.hpp:23,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/detail/tss_ptr.hpp:25,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/detail/call_stack.hpp:20,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/impl/handler_alloc_hook.ipp:19,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/handler_alloc_hook.hpp:80,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:19,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:24,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\boost_1_56_0/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\gazebo\build\install\Debug\include\gazebo-6.0/gazebo/transport/Connection.hh:23,
                 from C:\Users\peter\gz-ws\gazebo\build\install\Debug\include\gazebo-6.0/gazebo/transport/transport.hh:3,
                 from C:\Users\peter\wpilib\cpp\current\sim\include/DriverStation.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\peter\wpilib\cpp\current\sim\include/RobotBase.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\peter\wpilib\cpp\current\sim\include/WPILib.h:35,
                 from ..\src\OI.h:11,
                 from ..\src\OI.cpp:8: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/psdk_inc/_socket_types.h:11:9: error: 'UINT_PTR' does not name a type  typedef UINT_PTR SOCKET;
```

Comment: In my `mingw` socket declared as `typedef UINT_PTR SOCKET;`, and `UINT_PTR` declared as `typedef unsigned int UINT_PTR,*PUINT_PTR;` in header `basetsd.h`. Try to include `basetsd.h` before `boost::asio` headers.

Comment: also add `ws2_32.lib` to your project

Comment: I tried adding `basetd.h` to no avail. If things go wront at linking time I'll try the second suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, adding the following to all my .cpp files seems to have fixed that particular problem. I've noticed that everyone seems to be putting this at the top, but I don't see the connection between this and `UINT_PTR`, which is defined in `basetsd.h`

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  // Ensure that Winsock2.h is included before Windows.h
  #include <Winsock2.h>
#endif
```

If anyone figure out why this fixes it, I'd love to know

Comment: `windows.h` includes `winsock.h`, `winsock2.h` disables `winsock.h` when included. There is a macro, that do the same thing, but I can't find it...

Comment: I found, `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` excludes APIs such as Cryptography, DDE, RPC, Shell, and Windows Sockets. So you can define  `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before `windows.h` and include `winsock2.h` after `windows.h`

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how does winsock2 have anything to do with this? Does it somehow effect basetsd.h? BTW I think you're looking for win32-lean-and-mean

Comment: I see...I suppose since winsock2 us already included by boost and I'm not including either that or windows.h I'll use the macro

Comment: Actually, when I use asio, I do not need include `winsock2.h` or `windows.h`. I use `mingw` that ships with Qt 5.4. Boost version 1.57.

Comment: hm... -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN doesn't do it. Could be something else including winsock.h I suppose.

Comment: I'm not including either. or at least, I didn't until it started complaining. Now I have winsock2 included. It's probably boost or gazebo that's including things wrong...

Comment: I [asked the same question earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069904/why-does-mingw-w64-require-winsock2-to-be-manually-included) but didn't really get a clear answer.

Comment: Ya know, I wish I had one for you. My attitude right now is along the lines of screw windows let it burn in hell...