# Predict unit compilation order in order avoid redefinition

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, winsock, winsock2

Lets assume we have redefinition problem with [windows.h and winsock2.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399650/cannot-include-both-files-winsock2-windows-h) .

I know how to solve it. To be 100% sure just add line `_WINSOCKAPI_` in preprocessor definition. Or define `#define _WINSOCKAPI_` befor each `windows.h` include. But I would like to go more subtile way and define `_WINSOCKAPI_` just befor first include `windows.h`. How to know unit compilation order in order to place `#define _WINSOCKAPI_` in right place?

Please correct me if my understanding of redefinition problem is wrong.

Comment: Err.. I don't think you can predict it consistently. And even if you could for a particular compiler, it would surely be non-portable. Go with the preprocessor directive. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can predict the compilation order. I've not read the standards on this, but I think one of the premises of how c-code can be compiled is that every source file can be compiled independently. This enables you to do parallel builds etc.

So I wouldn't rely on your c/cpp files being compiled in a particular order.

However, the order that included files are processed is predictable; it is the order they are included in the c/cpp file.

I personally would include winsock2.h before windows.h as a solution to this problem rather than defining `_WINSOCKAPI_`, but defining that as a preprocessor def is an interesting idea.