# C++ Multipe Definition of Enum error when including classes that inherit from same parent

Tags: c++

I have the following class structure

```cpp
// shape.h
enum colors {RED=0, BLUE, GREEN};

class Shape {
    public:
        colors col;
        void setColor(colors c) {
            col = c;
        }
};

// circle.h
#include "Shape.h"
class Circle: public Shape {};

// rect.h
#include "Shape.h"
class Rect: public Shape {};
```

In my `main.cpp` I include both, `Circle` and `Rect`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Rect.h"
#include "Circle.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this leads to an error: `error: multiple definition of 'enum colors'`, because they are both inheriting from `Shape`. I am new to C++ and wonder what is the best practice to avoid/solve this?

Comment: You forgot include guards.

Comment: A simple way would be to move the `enum colors { RED = 0, BLUE, GREEN };` to the `public` section of the `Shape` class. Then use (say) `Shape::BLUE` when you want to refer to a particular colour.

Comment: Add #pragma once to all your headers files (or use #define and #ifndef to define include guards)

Comment: This is what [include guards](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-guards/) are for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Header File redefinition Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871224/c-header-file-redefinition-error), [C++ class redefinition error - Help me understand headers and linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485215/c-class-redefinition-error-help-me-understand-headers-and-linking)

Comment: @AdrianMole -- that's a simple solution to this particular error, but it doesn't fix the problem of missing include guards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Include_guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to avoid multiple inclusions:

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H
enum colors {red,green,blue};

class Shape {
    public:
        colors col;
        void setColor(colors c) {
            col = c;
        }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Addition to the  answer: in case using VC++, simply put ```#pragma once``` at the top of your *.h or *.hpp file which does exactly the same effect of using macros.

Comment: If you want to use compiler-specific remedies, you can use `#pragma once`; it isn't part of the standard, and it has subtle problems (i.e., it can't be reliably implemented, although it works for most build system configurations). In short: use normal include guards, as the code in this answer does.