# Type Redefinition Error (using Header Guards)

Tags: c++, redefinition

Disclaimer: [C++ Redefinition Header Files (winsock2.h)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372480/c-redefinition-header-files-winsock2-h) doesnt solved my problem

In this project, im trying to take a screenshot and then compressing it with libjpeg-turbo. The problem is that i get errors like

```
"sockaddr": "struct" Type redefinition
```

and

```
"nothl": Redefinition
```

ScreenWorker.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SCREENWORKER_H
#define SCREENWORKER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

#include <turbojpeg.h>

#include <Windows.h>

#include "..\API\NetClient.h"


class ScreenWorker {
private:
    NetClient* client;
public:
    int delay = 30;
    ScreenWorker(NetClient* client);
    HBITMAP GetScreenBmp(HDC hdc);
    void Update();
};
#endif
```

ScreenWorker.cpp:

```
#include "ScreenWorker.h"

ScreenWorker::ScreenWorker(NetClient* client) {
    this->client = client;
    Update();
}

HBITMAP ScreenWorker::GetScreenBmp(HDC hdc) {...}

void ScreenWorker::Update() {...}
```

The main.cpp (DLL-Entry):

```
#pragma once
#include "..\..\Base\API\API\GladOSClient.h"
#include "ScreenWorker.h"

using namespace std;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE Instance, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved) {
    return true;
}
```

NetClient.h (only Header part):

```
#pragma once
#ifndef NETCLIENT_H
#define NETCLIENT_H

#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#include "Utils.h"
#include "PacketHandler.h"
#include "Packet.h"

...

#endif
```

As you can see, i'm using header-guards everywhere, but nevertheless i get those errors. Seems like there is a problem with the including of "Windows.h"?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I guess the problem has something to do with the way libjpegturbo handles the including of "Windows.h". Currently i have no real way of solving this issue. Maybe im trying exporting the function i need in a seperated DLL... hopefully this will solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Redefinition Header Files (winsock2.h)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372480/c-redefinition-header-files-winsock2-h)

Comment: Already saw this thread, but didnt found a solution for my problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Classic issue.

Just remove this line from `NetClient.h`

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

The inclusion of `<Winsock2.h`> will pull in `<windows.h>` for you and correct all those redefine issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the errors stay the same. I quess the problem is at this point: 
       #include <turbojpeg.h>
       #include <Windows.h>
But i dont know why.

Comment: Remove all references to `#include <windows.h>` and replace with `#include <winsock2.h>`

Comment: Including the one in `ScreenWorker.h`

Comment: If i replace the `include <windows.h>` in `ScreenWorker.h`, it doesnt find the  functions like `BitBlt`, `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, `GetDC`, ... anymore. I know it doesnt make any sense, but it is like that.