# How do I deal with both winnt.h and ntstatus.h both in the WDK?

Tags: wdk

I am compiling a program that gets an error because both winnt.h and ntstatus.h are included in the WDK. I compiled with preprocess to a file and found this:

```
#line 1 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.18362.0\\um\\winnt.h"
```

and this:

```
#line 1 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.18362.0\\shared\\ntstatus.h"
```

Here are my includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h> 
#include <winnt.h>
```

Here is the error I get:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ntstatus.h(66,14): warning C4005: 'STATUS_WAIT_0': macro redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(2496): message : see previous definition of 'STATUS_WAIT_0'
```

Is there a define I need to use to tell VS not to open both?

Answer (score 4):

I was using the dokan library. I found that dokan.h includes ntstatus.h and there is a define called WIN32_NO_STATUS to take care of that.

Answer (score 3):

Add `UMDF_USING_NTSTATUS` define

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28995416)

Comment: That define will fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

A general Windows header inclusion sequence that gives the NTSTATUS codes without the macro redefinitions (e.g. STATUS_SUCCESS) plus fixes a common WinSock issue:

```
#define UMDF_USING_NTSTATUS // facilitate clean inclusion of ntstatus.h header further below
#include <winsock2.h>       // put before windows.h to fix macro redefinition issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372836/1173555
#include <windows.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
```

Credit to Dmytro for the UMDF_USING_NTSTATUS insight.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you can use exact value instead of NT status macro.
Then you do not need to `#include <ntstatus.h>` anymore
For example, you could use `0` instead of `STATUS_SUCCESS` in your code.

Hope it help.