Being inundated with macro redefinition from ntstatus.h
Despite having added the #define, I am still receiving the same bunch of warnings, twice (as many times the below header is #included) for a total of 100+ warnings:
#ifndef UMDF_USING_NTSTATUS
#define UMDF_USING_NTSTATUS
#endif // !UMDF_USING_NTSTATUS

#include <windows.h>
#include <memoryapi.h>
#include <ntsecapi.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <Sddl.h>

class MyClass
{
protected:
    static NTSTATUS MyMethod();
};


But I still get a bunch of warnings:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\SDKDDKVer.h(223): message : see previous definition of '_WIN32_WINNT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\ntstatus.h(66,1): warning C4005: 'STATUS_WAIT_0': macro redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\winnt.h(2549): message : see previous definition of 'STATUS_WAIT_0'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\ntstatus.h(223,1): warning C4005: 'STATUS_ABANDONED_WAIT_0': macro redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\winnt.h(2550): message : see previous definition of 'STATUS_ABANDONED_WAIT_0'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\ntstatus.h(246,1): warning C4005: 'STATUS_USER_APC': macro redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\winnt.h(2551): message : see previous definition of 'STATUS_USER_APC'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\ntstatus.h(282,1): warning C4005: 'STATUS_TIMEOUT': macro redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\winnt.h(2552): message : see previous definition of 'STATUS_TIMEOUT'

What is required to stop that?

AFAICS, UMDF_USING_NTSTATUS doesn't apply to normal user-mode projects, only to UMDF drivers.  Your example doesn't need all of those #includes, just <windows.h> by itself.

Windows headers can be a bit picky about their ordering; maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903656/how-do-i-deal-with-both-winnt-h-and-ntstatus-h-both-in-the-wdk can give some hints?

These warnings are generally down to one of two reasons: 1 Headers are included in the wrong order, or 2 Code includes headers it shouldn't. The documentation generally names the header that introduces any given symbol and the header your code should include. This follows the pattern: "Header: foo.h (include bar.h)". Do not #include <foo.h>.

@RemyLebeau The MWE does not but the project does.

As suggested by @linspectable in comments, I moved the #include of the class in the question to the top of the #includes in the consuming class, and the warnings disappeared.

With this particular example, I use:
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(4005 : disable)
#include <ntstatus.h>
#pragma warning(pop)

to simply disable the message for the particular header. I have not found a way to only have the symbols #define'd once.

That did not clear the warnings.
