# Problem with winsocks after project migration to VS2022

Tags: sockets, winapi

Headers order below

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

All code was written and debugged in VS2019, and compiles there fine. But after migration appears classic problem of misordering winsockets headers.
As that

> error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition

Anybody any suggestions, what is the cause ?

Comment: This "as is" with Visual Studio 2022 should compile fine. Are you sure you're not hitting this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372480/c-redefinition-header-files-winsock2-h

Comment: Headers included in one file in one place

Comment: you drop important information from error message - 1. where sockaddr was defined first time and 2. where is sockaddr redefined

Comment: Please also show a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN broken.After commenting line #include <winsock.h> , from windows.h project builds without errors. WTF ? What wrong with my Visual Studio, how to fix this issue?

Comment: `#include <winsock.h>` is still guarded for me behind an `#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` in my VS 2022 setup. What SDK version are you referencing? And can you please provide a [mcve] including the **full** error diagnostic?